# Deployment Error – UIType isn't updateable for custom apps

Tags: deployment, change-set

Running into an change set deployment error I've never seen before:

> UIType isn't updateable for custom apps

I've got just about all of the dependencies already deployed. And the only information I can find about this field is that its a boolean that denotes which version of the web UI is being used (lightning or classic). I really can't allow this to cost me my deadline and would be grateful for any thoughts from the community here.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?